# Send UDP Packet to Memcached via Netcat

Tags: netcat, udp, memcached

I am attempting to send the `stats` command to memcached via netcat, however, I am not getting anything back from memcached...

I have tried

```
echo "stats" > commands.txt
nc -u 127.0.0.1 11211 < commands.txt
```

I have also tried

```
echo stats | nc -u 127.0.0.1 11211
```

From what I have read on the bottom of the [Memcached Documentation](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt), line 1176, the command when being sent might have to include

```
Each UDP datagram contains a simple frame header, followed by data in the
same format as the TCP protocol described above. In the current
implementation, requests must be contained in a single UDP datagram, but
responses may span several datagrams. (The only common requests that would
span multiple datagrams are huge multi-key "get" requests and "set"
requests, both of which are more suitable to TCP transport for reliability
reasons anyway.)

The frame header is 8 bytes long, as follows (all values are 16-bit integers 
in network byte order, high byte first):

0-1 Request ID
2-3 Sequence number
4-5 Total number of datagrams in this message
6-7 Reserved for future use; must be 0
```

My question is, How do I send the `stats` command via udp to Memcached using netcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked, You must specify the frameheader

```
printf '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00stats\r\n' | nc -u 127.0.0.1 11211
```